# Why can I not force ul to behave as a table-row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `bootstrap3`, and I would like to have a `navbar`, where all `nav` items are spaced through the whole width of the bar.

To achieve this my only option was to make the bar behave like a `table`, `-row`, respectively `-cell`.

I've got the right markup & css, but apparently somehow I cannot force `display: table-row;` on my `ul`.

#### [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/OzIhagu/4/edit)

Odd thing is that:

- Both firefox & chromium report that although `table-row` is the most important rule, they apply `block`

  [image]
- This only happens when I include `bootstrap3` (try toggling it in the live example)

#### HTML

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="">
            <a href="#">Homeen</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="#">News</a>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.collapse.navbar-collapse {
  display: table !important;
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar .nav {
  display: table-row !important;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
.navbar .nav > li {
  display: table-cell !important;
  background: #39f;
  float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out

I just had to unfloat `.nav`

```
.nav {
   float: none;
}
```

### [Working example](http://jsbin.com/OzIhagu/5/edit)

*Sigh*, another lost hour. But I will leave the question up, maybe it saves someone's time.

Comment: You're going to loose more than an hour... I bet in a week you'll find a weird bug, and in a month you'll find another one, and in six months a third. I've been burned by this in the past, it's not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it a table man.

All the crazy code you're going to have to write to make this work without any browser bugs is going to be far more ugly than a table tag.

Comment: Yes, I know, that this is one option but I would like to adhere to bootstrap3's markup (though I know that through this I modify completely the behavior of the elementS) - I didn't downvote :)

Comment: upvote: In the end I've used custom (js) layout, leaving `bootstrap3` behind, since the desired layout was too custom, to hack it together with html elements.

Comment: @Matyas you should also accept the answer, since it's how you ended up solving the problem. Or else accept your own answer.